# Fun mathematical model to announce pregnancy to husband

Tags: recreational-mathematics, mathematical-modeling, hidden-markov-models

My husband is a mathematical modeler and I would love to give him a model to announce to him that we're pregnant! He is a pharmacometrician and a neurologist and often uses R, PKPD, and Markov models, but also works avidly with other mathematics (though I wouldn't be able to tell you what). Is it possible to have some type of model/equation to equal pregnant/biological chemistry of being pregnant? My knowledge on these subjects are minute so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Congratulations :) :) I do not know about this. Hope some one helps you :)

Comment: $1+1=3?{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Something that first came to mind for me was [matrix encryption](http://www.austincc.edu/lrosen/1314/webact2/webact2.htm), not sure if that is what you're looking for or not.

Comment: Thank you @WaveX --> I'm not sure what a matrix encryption is (I'm in a completely opposite field) but, thank you for your support by comment!

Comment: And thank you @cello for the congrats! :) He's on a business trip, so it will be a great welcome home surprise!

Comment: Congratulations on (re)discovering a three element group with two generators. You could tell him that's what the two of you have done.

Comment: @quasi Or $\,1+1 \ge 3\,$ as the case may be ;-) P.S. To the OP, congrats!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Congratulations!

Here's a possible fun approach:

Ask him to convert the following to base $36$:

$\frac{222,931,132,460,168,112}{332,378,040,005,725}$

The answer, in decimal form, is:

$670\frac{237,845,656,332,362}{332,378,040,005,725}$

Converted to base $36$, where $a=10$, $b=11$, and so on up to $z=35$, that works out to:

$im.pregnant\overline{impregnant}_{36}$

He should probably [use Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=222931132460168112%2F332378040005725%20in%20base%2036), and make sure he clicks the "More digits" button, until it sinks in.

Comment: That would be $\frac{3,688,558,795,838,123,575,815,168}{4,738,381,338,321,616,895}$ in base 36. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @GreyMatters! I think he'll love this :)

Answer (score 2):

A mother is $21$ years older than her son.

In six years' time the child will be $5$ times younger than her mother.

Question: Where is the father?

*

Attention to the question: Where is the father?

*

Attention to the question: Where is the father?

*

> Solution:
>
> The boy is now ten years old.
>
> The mother has today $Y$ years.
>
> $\implies X + 21 = Y$
>
> In $6$ years:
>
> $5 (X + 6) = Y + 6$
>
> So
>
> $5X + 30 = X + 21 + 6$
>
> $4X = -3$
>
> $X = -\dfrac 34$
>
> The boy is now $-\dfrac 34$ years, that is, $-9$ months.

So the father is ....